# Difference between ASturct arr[] and ASturct * arr[]

Tags: c, pointers

What is difference between ASturct arr[] and ASturct* arr[]?

```
ASturct array[]
ASturct * array[]
```

Thanks for answer!

Comment: Do you know what is `char ` and `char *`?

Comment: yeah I know but what is the difference? char is type of variable and char* is a pointer of char type

Comment: @EmilMein No, both `char` and `char*` are types. Different types. Same with `ASturct` (whatevfer that is) and `ASturct*`. Two types, but two different types. You can a variable of type `ASturct` and another variable of type `ASturct*`.

Comment: Now think both just as data types and answer your own question.

Comment: Oh, and unless you're declaring `array` as an argument to a function, you can't have an empty size for arrays.

Comment: Finally, you probably need to [find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and start reading from the beginning.

Comment: @Some programmer dude But if you create array(first or 2nd) i will get pointer to the first element and elements are represented by pointers (like from definition array is a set of pointers).

Comment: No you are misunderstanding how arrays work. They can *decay* to a pointer to its first element. But an array is not by itself a pointer. And each element in an array is a *value* and not a pointer (unless the value *is* a pointer, like in the second example you show).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a basic misunderstanding about how arrays and pointers work.

Lets take a very simple example:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;

int array1[3] = { a, b, c };
```

The above code creates an array of three `int` values. In memory it will look something like

```
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
+---+---+---+
```

The variables `a`, `b` and `c` are not anywhere in the array, the values of those variables were copied into the array when the array was initialized.

Now lets take a ***very different*** example:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;

int *array2[3] = { &a, &b, &c };
```

Now we have an array *of pointers*, and initialize each element to point to the variables `a`, `b` and `c`. It will look something like this in memory

```
+----+----+----+
| &a | &b | &c |
+----+----+----+
 |    |    |
 |    |    v
 |    |    +---+
 |    |    | 3 |
 |    |    +---+
 |    v    
 |    +---+
 |    | 2 |
 |    +---+
 |
 v
 +---+
 | 1 |
 +---+
```

Both `array1` and `array2` in the example above are array with three elements, but the similarities end there. The type and value of each element in the arrays are very different from each other. For `array1` each element is a single `int`, it holds a number (like e.g. `1` for `array1[0]`). For `array2` each element is a *pointer* to an `int` value, and its value is the address of that `int` value.

Comment: Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

```
ASturct  array[]
```

Above one is array of type ASturct .

```
ASturct * array[]
```

And this one is array of pointers (which are of type ASturct).